# How to change the type of input tag(date to text) in jquery.?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

can you please tell me How to change the type of input tag(date to text) in `jQuery` on button click.

Actually I want to do some task then again i want to change the type (text to date.)

Answer (score 1):

NOT sure you want that kind of code, any ways here it is

```
$('#dataid').attr('type', 'input');
```

> [DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/WuUkd/)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#buttonId').click(function() {
    input = $('#inputId');
    if(input.attr('type') == 'text') {
      input.attr('type', 'date');
    } else {
      input.attr('type', 'text');
    }
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TuvXm/

Answer (score 1):

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#foo").prop("type","checkbox"); //instead of checkbox, you may put any type
})
```

Jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/ZT6Xy/1/

Answer (score 1):

HERE is the working sample [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Akki619/HazdQ/)

HTML:

```
<input type="date" id="inputID"/>
<br>
<br>
<button id="submit">Submit</button>
```

Script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

$("#submit").click(function(){

  var a = document.getElementById("inputID");
  a.type="text";                      
});
```

});

See the below screenshot type is changed to text.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
if(input.prop('type') == 'text') {
    $('input[type=text]').prop('type','date');
 }
else {
    $('input[type=text]').prop('type','date');
 }
});
```